Docker ENTRYPOINT not working as intended
I'm new to docker and I'm having an issue with the ENTRYPOINT argument in the dockerfile. I'm working on a project called F1Tenth and I am using their premade docker image. I am running it on a jetson nano and I am trying to figure out how to source these two files (/opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash and install/local_setup.bash) for ROS2. After some research I figured the best thing to try was to run a script that sources these and have that script run using ENTRYPOINT. I tried A BUNCH of things but nothing is working, when the container starts I still need to manually source the files in the terminal. I need this to work because the jetson is going to be attached to an RC car and it needs to be headless and no ssh.
Here is my entrypoint.sh (its inside of the docker image dir)
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/ors/foxy/setup.bash
source install/local_setup.bash
exec "$@"

Here is my DockerFile:
FROM ros:foxy

SHELL \["/bin/bash", "-c"\]

# dependencies

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
apt-get install -y git \
nano \
vim \
python3-pip \
libeigen3-dev \
tmux \
ros-foxy-rviz2
RUN apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN pip3 install transforms3d

# f1tenth gym

RUN git clone https://github.com/f1tenth/f1tenth_gym
RUN cd f1tenth_gym && \
pip3 install -e .

# ros2 gym bridge

RUN mkdir -p sim_ws/src/f1tenth_gym_ros
COPY . /sim_ws/src/f1tenth_gym_ros
RUN source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash && \
cd sim_ws/ && \
apt-get update --fix-missing && \
rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y && \
colcon build

WORKDIR '/sim_ws'
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

I've tried various other DockerFile setups. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the point of ENTRYPOINT

Why are you escaping [ and ] in the Dockerfile? This seems unnecessary.

How are you running the container?  The entrypoint wrapper script seems fine, though I might avoid the non-standard source command.  The ENTRYPOINT declaration runs ./entrypoint.sh out of the current directory but in the previous line you copy it to /entrypoint.sh in the filesystem root; is that a problem?

In your entrypoint.sh you reference /opt/ors/foxy/setup.bash but I could only find /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash on the image (they differ in the second part of the path). I'm assuming that this is a typo and you meant the latter file. It's also the path that you mention in your text.
So I suggest changing your entrypoint.sh as follows:
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
source install/local_setup.bash

exec "$@"

I've fiddled with the Dockerfile a bit too. You don't need to change SHELL if you source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.sh rather than /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash. Also moved the WORKDIR earlier which means you don't need to cd sim_ws/.
You don't need to make these changes though and the updated entrypoint.sh should be sufficient for the image to build and run successfully.
FROM ros:foxy

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y git \
        nano \
        vim \
        python3-pip \
        libeigen3-dev \
        tmux \
        ros-foxy-rviz2 && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
    pip3 install transforms3d

RUN git clone https://github.com/f1tenth/f1tenth_gym
RUN cd f1tenth_gym && \
    pip3 install -e .

RUN mkdir -p sim_ws/src/f1tenth_gym_ros
COPY . /sim_ws/src/f1tenth_gym_ros

WORKDIR /sim_ws

RUN . /opt/ros/foxy/setup.sh && \
    apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y && \
    colcon build

COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

I also note that you were sourcing the /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash script twice, once in the Dockerfile itself and then again via the entrypoint.sh script. Is this intentional? Is it really necessary?
